# Do something about [optimisation] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just noticed the [optimisation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) tag, and two possible problems with it.

1. "Optimization" is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimization,optimisation&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,optimization;,c0;.t1;,optimisation;,c0) than "optimisation" in both [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimization,optimisation&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,optimization;,c0;.t1;,optimisation;,c0) and [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimization,optimisation&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,optimization;,c0;.t1;,optimisation;,c0), so it should probably be [optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) instead of [optimisation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation).
2. It is vague. In this case it was used for code optimization, but it could be used for for energy use optimization, circuit simplicity optimization, etc.

What should we do with this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).**

*Changes:*

- Edited question and renamed to [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization)
- Added synonyms: [code-optimisation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimisation) → [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization)

I've declined to do anything with the vague [optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) tag. Since the question was edited, it's an orphaned tag. If there's another type of optimization that comes up (i.e. energy), we can change add synonyms for the different spellings.

The reason for that is if I would've added [optimisation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) → [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization) and [optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) → [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization), any time a user adds either of those tags, it will, **without warning,** replace the tag to [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization). IMHO this is a major flaw in the system. It should warn the user.

A quick note: from searches, it seems like spelling it with a `z` is the most common way, but is still widely used. However, since SE is a US based company, we'll stick to US spelling. I know that Stack Exchange has users and countless countries, but it's simpler to stick to one version of English spelling, the one that's built into the engine/code base.

Comment: Adding a synonym for [tag:optimisation] --> [tag:optimization] shouldn't result in it being re-tagged as [tag:code-optimization]. It may suggest it as a possible existing tag, but it shouldn't automatically change it (unless there's a pretty serious bug...)

Comment: @Peter Haha, oops editing it now. I meant [tag:code-optimization] for the second tag in the paragraph. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I would just retag that question to have [code-optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-optimization). [optimisation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) could be made to be a synonym of [optimization](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization), but that seems unnecessary to me.